# iOS Multiple AVPlayer objects results in loss of audio/video sync

Tags: iphone, ipad, synchronization, avplayer

I've been trying to use two different `AVQueuePlayer` objects within my app. The first player plays a series of short video clips streamed over the net. The second object plays only one video, but it is much longer in length. It is also streamed. I have verified all the clips have proper audio/video sync.

What I've noticed is that if I create one `AVPlayer` object after having created another one beforehand, the audio/video sync in the second player is lost. The audio is played between about 800ms - 1500ms too early.

I've tried a number of things, including adding a delay between cleaning up the first player and allocating the second player, removing all calls to the `AudioSession` code etc. None of this seems to help. Very occasionally the audio will be in sync, but it really only happens about 1 in 30 times.

Has anyone else seen the same behavior? Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks to anyone that can help!

Answer (score 3):

I'm facing the same problem myself. I came across some information in the AVPlayerLayer documentation:

> During playback, AVPlayer may
>   compensate for temporal drift between
>   its visual output and its audible
>   output to one or more
>   independently-clocked audio output
>   devices by adjusting the timing of its
>   associated player layers. The effects
>   of these adjustments are usually very
>   small; however, clients that wish to
>   remain entirely unaffected by such
>   adjustments may wish to place other
>   layers for which timing is important
>   into independently timed subtrees of
>   their layer trees.
>
> You can create arbitrary numbers of
>   player layers with the same AVPlayer
>   object. Only the most-recently-created
>   player layer will actually display the
>   video content on-screen.

Unfortunately I haven't deciphered this into actual code but I figured it might help point you in the right direction. If you do come up with a solution then please post it here and I will do the same.

Comment: After doing some more testing it seems like the A/V sync is fine if I get rid of the first player before calling play on the second.  [player pause];
[player release];
player = nil;
[player2 play];    But it seems like you said you are already doing this right?

Comment: I actually discovered that this was due to the fact that the first player wasn't being released properly. There were references still held by the system to the player, and it wasn't being removed. Removing any time observers and/or timers before trying to deallocate is pretty important.

Comment: According to my testing, it seems that this problem occurs on older devices like 3GS (with os4) and not on iphone4. Multiple AVPlayer objects work fine on iphone4. I have yet to test it on iPad1 (with os4).