# AVPlayer restart sync issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, avplayer

Hi all
Im working with AVPlayer app to run on an iPad and just getting my head around it. Currently stuck with an issue that i cant seem to get the avplayer to restart a currently playing file safely. The video doesnt need to be finished for a call for the command to restart is called.

```
[player[currentPage] seekToTime:startTime toleranceBefore:startTime toleranceAfter:startTime];



[player[currentPage] play];
```

is what im using at the moment and it works majority of the time but sometimes the video seems to go out of sync with the sound . that is to say the sound restarts fine but the video seems to be paused and doesnt restart until the sound catches back up with it.

Anyone have experience with this or can point me in the right direction to research it myself. I have gone through the avplayer class files on the apple dev site and have been unlucky with searching for similar problems.

Thanks for any help

G

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer for this question:
[iOS Multiple AVPlayer objects results in loss of audio/video sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002926/ios-multiple-avplayer-objects-results-in-loss-of-audio-video-sync/5514275#5514275)

Comment: Hi steve, thanks for that but didnt end up being the issue and i may never know what is. the problem just automagically disappeared.slightly concerning but ive moved on to bigger and more depressing bugs. yay?